# Мы помним и заботимся о своих ветеранах

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, типы-ошибок

**Мы помним и заботимся о своих ветеранах.**
Какая грамматическая ошибка в этом предложении?

Comment: Если вопрос о грамматической ошибке, то почему стоит метка "стилистические-ошибки"?

Answer (score 5):

*Мы помним и заботимся о своих ветеранах.*

Желательно: *Мы помним о своих ветеранах и заботимся о них.*

Я думаю, что здесь между глаголами **нет семантической однородности**, они описывают разные ситуации. Это различие лучше обозначить и в структуре предложения.

У Розенталя использование общего существительного допустимо, но, возможно, не для каждого случая его следует применить даже при совпадении падежного управления.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_08)

При двух или нескольких управляющих словах общее зависимое слово **допустимо,** когда каждое из управляющих слов требует того же падежа и предлога, например: читать и конспектировать книгу; подбирать и готовить кадры; протравливать и яровизировать семена; надеяться и рассчитывать на помощь.

Comment: Согласен, но вопрос остается: ошибка ли это, грамматическая ли?

Comment: Понятие о семантической однородности входит в грамматику. К примеру, грамматически однородные определения могут быть семантически однородными или неоднородными, и это зависит от смысла. Наличие общего зависимого слова подчеркивает семантическую однородность (спаянность) глаголов, которая в действительности отсутствует. Соответственно, это можно считать  не только стилистической, но грамматической неточностью. (Стилистическая неточность предложения определяется на слух)

Answer (score 1):

Грамматической ошибки я здесь не вижу.
Более того, в некоторых случаях словосочетание "о своих ветеранах" было бы даже уместно:
 *"Они заботятся о своих ветеранах"*.

Но в данном случае необходимо, конечно же, говорить:
"Мы помним и заботимся о **наших** ветеранах".
И тут даже вопрос не столько стилистики, сколько элементарного воспитания и реального уважения к **нашим** ветеранам.

Comment: Возможно, имеется в виду, что по контексту лучше подходит "помнить ветеранов", чем "помнить о ветеранах" (см. управление глагола "помнить"). Например: мы помним наших ветеранов и заботимся о них.

Comment: @grizzly Думаю, автор вопроса имел в виду именно  "помнить ветеранов", но я с ним не огласен. "Помнить ветеранов" больше подходит, когда говорят об  ушедших, а о живых говорят, что помнят О них.

Answer (score 0):

> Какая грамматическая ошибка в этом предложении?

Думаю, автор вопроса думает, что здесь ошибка в построении предложения с однородными членами (Пример такой ошибки: *Страна любила и гордилась поэтом*). Если автор думает, что нужно заменить "помнить о ветеранах" на  "помнить ветеранов", то я с ним не согласен. "Помнить кого-то" больше подходит, когда говорят об ушедших, а о живых лучше говорить, что мы помним О них.

Употребление "своих" или "наших" зависит от контекста. Например: *Мы в России заботимся о своих ветеранах, а другие страны пусть позаботятся о своих.*